# Is it possible to define an inverse of the main three trig. functions without domain restrictions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Ok, I know that the main three main trigonometric functions, that is the tangent, sine, and cosine, are periodic and thus not one-to-one, but onto. And, since an inverse requires a function to be onto and one-to-one, trigonometeic functions can, by definition, not have inverses. However, I was wondering if it is possible, perhaps in some other field of maths, to rigorously define the same trigonometric functions in such a manner that they can indeed have inverses without restrictions.

Comment: We can speak of the relation $\arcsin$ but it will not be a function.

Comment: Yes, but my question was addressing whether some field of maths allows us to define a function for the inverse.

Comment: Maybe you mean the theory of binary relations?

Comment: I have heard rather vaguely of the theory of binary relations and I know the main concepts but I do not believe they tolerate trigonometric functions to have a well-defined non-restricted inverse, although, they can prove that they can't have such an inverse, However, I am wondering whether any field within maths does indeed allow for such an inverse.

Comment: You can force the inverse $g$ of a non-bijective function $f$ but $g$ will be a relation not a function. Such relations are sometimes called multifunction; they are used for example in complex analysis.

Comment: Thank you, I believe that answers my rather futile question.